# Using R for spatial data from SQL Server but getting little endian error

Tags: sql-server, r, geospatial

I am trying to get WKB data from SQL Server into an R object.

1. Get data from SQL Server query

   `data <- sqlQuery(cn, 'SELECT TOP 1 geography::STGeomFromWKB(Coordinates.STAsBinary(), 4269) as coord from Geo;')`
2. Serialize raw data

   `wkb <- serialize(data$coord, NULL)`
3. Create data frame

   `obj <- readWKB(wkb)`

Step 3 always generates this error:

> Error in (function (WkbGeom, Id)  : Only little endian is supported

I have also tried the following:

```
wkb <- serialize(data$coord, NULL, NA, FALSE)
wkb <- serialize(data$coord, NULL, NA, TRUE)
```

With no luck.

How can I convert the raw data into a little endian format?